# hibernate ManyToOne why 2 queries are generated instead of one?

Tags: hibernate, orm, many-to-one

MyTable is a table in my Oracle DB, it has a CMP_ID to join the COMPANIES table.

Here is the Java implementation :

```
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns( { @JoinColumn(name = "CMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "CMP_ID", nullable = false) })
@XmlTransient
Company company;
...
}
```

In my JSP Page, i managed to display the MyTable:

```
${MyTable.company.cmpName}
```

But Hibernate generated 2 SELECTs :
one for the MyObject , and another one to fecth the Company name.

How do  i fetch all the informations i want in only one query using Hibernate ? (all fields in MyTable, plus the Company name in the Companies table)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use a custom query, **set up the fetching strategy as EAGER**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="CMP_ID", referencedColumnName="CMP_ID", nullable=false)
private Company company;
```

Just an advice: prefer to use @JoinColumns if you have more than one @JoinColumn. Otherwise, use just @JoinColumn. keep in mind HQL queries overrides default fetching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way hibernate works.  See http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernate-query-101/ for more information.

Comment: so, if i read well, the only way to change this behaviour is to use a custom query ? no other option / annotation?

Comment: You can also use a left join in the query, but I don't think lazy fetch will work.